# Can't adjust apache says bad_httpd_conf

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I installed Apache and edited `sites_enabled/000_default` as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

ServerName lokal
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName firsatbulur.bom
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to go http://firsatbulur.bom:

```
Site Temporarily Unavailable
We apologize for the inconvenience. Please contact the webmaster/ tech support immediately to have them rectify this.

error id: "bad_httpd_conf"
```

I tried to audit the logs  with **tail -f  /var/log/apache2/*** according to this there is no error.

Please note: I can access noıramlly by 127.0.0.1.
My questions:

1. why does Apache report such an error?
2. Who could think to give out such an error, but not to log it?
3. How can I solve this? I'm roaming half day but there is no occasion except dreamhosters.

This machine is running Mint Katya, (ubuntu 11.04).

Comment: My bad, I got on a bus. And realized that domain, http://firsatbulur.bom in fact pointing to dreamhost.

It was not my servers giving bad_http_conf it was dreamhost! I tweaked it from hosts file.

Comment: If your problem is solved, it would be kind to submit it as an answer, and mark it as accepted, so it won't show up in the unanswered question list, and might help someone else with that error message in the future.

Comment: I have 4 hours left! Stackoverflow limitation for newbies

Answer (score 0):

As a general approach: go get an unedited httpd.conf (ideally you will have kept one, if not download a new copy) and install that. Does Apache now work? Assuming so, make the changes incrementally until it stops working. The answer will then, we hope, become clear.

Comment: It is not httpd.conf, it is default site file. Apache is working if you enter 127.0.0.1 in url bar

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you there is a syntax error in your httpd configuration.  Try running this command:

```
apachectl configtest
```

This should tell you what part of your configuration it doesn't understand.  If you need more help after that, add the output of that command to your question.

Comment: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
Syntax OK